# Swagger - ошибка пути

Tags: java, swagger

В Swagger есть проблема на вызов реста возвращающий `List<Map<String, Object>>` (вверху появляется сообщение)

```
Errors
Resolver error at paths./api/v1/getEntity/{integrationCode}.post.responses.200.schema.items.$ref
Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Map«string,object» does not exist in document
```

пробовал добавить в `SwaggerConfig`

```
.alternateTypeRules(
                    AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
                            typeResolver.resolve(List.class, typeResolver.resolve(Map.class, typeResolver.resolve(String.class, Object.class))), Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
                    )
            )
```

сам контроллер

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/")
public class RetrieveController {

@Autowired
RetrieverService retrieverService;

@PostMapping(value = "getEntity/{integrationCode}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public List<Map<String, Object>> getList(@PathVariable String integrationCode, @RequestBody RetrieveParam retrieveParam) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> integration = retrieverService.getIntegration(integrationCode, retrieveParam);
    return integration;
   }
}
```

не получается таким образом решить вопрос, возможно есть еще варианты?

Comment: Какие исходные данные? Как можно воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin - UP post. Вся ругань свагера идет на значение Object в мапе, как ее решить, кроме как заменить на стринг, хз..